# XNA 4: RenderTarget2D textures getting transparent on fullscreen

Tags: c#, textures, xna-4.0, rendertargets

I'm generating a `Texture2D` object using `RenderTarget2D` as in the following code

```
public static Texture2D GetTextTexture(string text, Vector2 position, SpriteFont font, Color foreColor, Color backColor, Texture2D background=null)
{
            int width = (int)font.MeasureString(text).X;
            int height = (int)font.MeasureString(text).Y;

            GraphicsDevice device = Settings.game.GraphicsDevice;
            SpriteBatch spriteBatch = Settings.game.spriteBatch;

            RenderTarget2D renderTarget = new RenderTarget2D(device, width,
            height, false, SurfaceFormat.Color, DepthFormat.Depth24Stencil8,
            device.PresentationParameters.MultiSampleCount, RenderTargetUsage.DiscardContents);

            device.SetRenderTarget(renderTarget);
                device.Clear(backColor);
                spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.Opaque);
                if (background != null) spriteBatch.Draw(background, new Rectangle(0, 0, 70, 70), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.End();
                spriteBatch.Begin();
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font, text, position, foreColor, 0, new Vector2(0), 0.8f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
                spriteBatch.End();
            device.SetRenderTarget(null);
            ResetGraphicsDeviceSettings();
            return (Texture2D)renderTarget;
}
```

It's working all fine. But when I `ToggleFullScreen()` (and vice-versa), the previous textures are getting transparent. However, the new textures after that are being generated correctly.

What can be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

`ToggleFullScreen()` causes the `GraphicsDevice` to be reset and when the `GraphicsDevice` is reset the default behavior of the `RenderTarget2D` is to loose its data.

You have 2 options.

1. You can copy the color data into a Texture2D.

   ```
   Color[] texdata = new Color[Width * Height];
   renderTarget.GetData(texdata);
   texture.SetData(texdata); //<-- you would want to return this texture
   ```
2. You can hook into the [Content Lost Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.rendertarget2d.contentlost.aspx) and rebuild the `RenderTarget2D` when needed.

Personally I recommend #1, especially it its a one time operation such as at level loading,  since it helps keep things simple since you're back to only dealing with standard Texture2Ds and everything is back on CPU side memory.

Comment: I have already tried `option 1`, it was not working. For `option 2`, Shawn Hargreaves at [this link](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/64831/397866.aspx) says that its slow. But I'm not much concerned about performance. I'm trying to resolve `The size of the data passed in is too large or too small for this resource` issue. Read at many places, still I'm trying to figure out this issue.

Comment: I still didn't understand `option 3`. Which `RenderTarget2D` shall I built inside the handler? Are you asking me to reset the `GraphicsDevice` settings?

Comment: Option 2 is slow if you do it every frame. It's reasonably fast if you do it once at start-up. Your exception is because you're using the API wrong (ask a new question if you need help). Option 3 requires a handler on every render target that doesn't get refreshed every frame.

Comment: And option 1 is actually incorrect. It allows you to set the render target back onto the device without clearing it. It has nothing to do with content-lost and does not solve that problem. (I have taken the liberty of editing the answer to reflect this.)